# HighCharts underscore of xAxis data

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to render my graphics in my web-based user interface. I am a novice programmer. I am receiving help from a number of folks. But, they and I cannot seem to remove the underscores from the x axis data values. I have searched the highcharts forum and see no mention of it there (I may have missed it). I am certain it is one of the options, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Do you have some code (JFiddle)? How Do you insert your data?

Comment: Which chart do you use, because only drilldown has a underscored labels.

Comment: The highcharts code in my program is over 17,000 lines long, so I do not know what code you might be interested in. A programmer wrote most of the code. It is highly flexible; we use several types of charts (line, area, pie, stacked area, bar, drill-down on the pie charts). In our code all the charts have the underscore for the x axis data. I am not sure what to show you.